# Error: "Fixing recursive fault, but reboot is needed" need to put acpi off

Tags: lubuntu, acer, acpi, aspire

I having trouble with a Acer Aspire 2010. Whenever I boot, just one moment after grub I get the error "Fixing recursive fault, but reboot is needed". So I searched for it, and I found this workaround: adding acpi=off to grub. Now it does boot, but I can't power off well. I always need to perform a hard-reset. The computer is running Lubuntu 12.04 (couldn't install normal ubuntu due to pae). Strange is that the live installer runs without problems. Also, removing the battery, disconnecting AC, etc... doesn't help.
Solution?

Comment: I've done some research, and I found out some things about DSDT. Now I tried to copy the DSDT table from the live installer to the real OS. I followed [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1036051) guide. However, it's not working. Am I doing something wrong?
Please answer, I'm getting really frustrated.

Comment: I have the same problem. It worked until kernel 3.2.0-17 with these options : acpi=enable pci=noacpi pci=assign-busse acpi=ht but not anymore with kernel 3.2.0-23

Comment: So at least I'm not the only one :)
Do you have a Acer Aspire 2010 too?