# Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 64-bit

Trying to install Ubuntu for the first time. Attempting to Dual Boot on a SSD with windows 10 fresh install. I have created a bootable USB from the ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso and when it boots i am getting stuck on the error "Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!" I have rebooted but each time it is the same.

I'm running a new Dell Inspiron 5999 with 8GB Ram.

Edit: I dont get anywhere significant in the installation. It simply boots starts listing various lines and then gives me the error message before i get a chance to really do anything. If I try to shut down I can get to what appears to be a command line but when I type anything it just starts a new line and nothing is returned.

I have tried with a different USB Boot loader to load the iso and have the same problem. I am going to try the latest version and then a 32 bit version to see if it makes any difference as the small bit of infomation I have found suggests trying that.

What else can I try?

Comment: Other possible duplicates: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126944/error-fixing-recursive-fault-but-reboot-is-needed-need-to-put-acpi-off and https://askubuntu.com/questions/50451/error-fixing-recursive-fault-but-reboot-is-needed and https://askubuntu.com/questions/50052/fixing-recursive-fault-but-reboot-is-needed-during-installation and https://askubuntu.com/questions/216895/powerbook-displays-fixing-recursive-fault-but-reboot-is-needed-and-stops-boot

Answer (score 0):

I got recently got this message about a "recursive fault" repeatedly when trying to install anything or even boot up my old Lenovo desktop.

After a lot of trial and error I replaced the graphics card to see if it might solve the problem.

It did!